# Django Rest Framework ManyToManyField ModelSerializer data format

Tags: django-rest-framework, django-orm

How do the appendices data has to look like to be valid? I am sending the data from a php website and tried several things that are parsed by the DJF to the following format. Both are invalid.

```
'information.appendices.file.0'
'information.appendices.file[0]'

class Information(models.Model):
    type = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    text = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    url = models.URLField(blank=True, null=True)
    appendices = models.ManyToManyField('Appendix')


class Appendix(models.Model):
    file = models.FileField(upload_to='information/appendices')


class AddInformationSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    appendices = AppendixSerializer(many=True, required=False)
```

Comment: Did you try setting the parser class to [MultiPartParser](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/parsers/) in the view? Which `Content-Type` header are you sending?

Comment: MultiPartParser is already used and Content-Type is multipart.